# Passing Values using Json in PHP and Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json, ajax

I am beginner of `Json`. There are some values contains in the `HTML table`, need to pass those values using `json` to `prescription.php` page. I tried, but after `ajax` success it shows a error message in error log:

`e = {readyState: 4, getResponseHeader: ƒ, getAllResponseHeaders: ƒ, setRequestHeader: ƒ, overrideMimeType: ƒ, …}`

Here is my `HTML`  code segments:

```
    <form method="post" id="prescriptionn" enctype="multipart/form-data">  
       <div class="table-responsive">
           <table class="table table-bordered mb-0" id="medical">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                         <th>Medicine Name</th>
                         <th>Morning</th>
                         <th>Noon</th>
                         <th>Night</th>
                         <th> <button type="button" name="add" id="add" 
                                class="btn btn-success btn-xs"> + </button>  </th>

                     </tr>
                 </thead>
                 <tbody id="rows"> 
                 </tbody>
            </table>
                        <br><br>
             <div align="center">
                <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $row['apt_id'] ?>" 
                          id="getapt" name="getapt" class="btn btn-primary">

                 <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $row['p_id'] ?>" 
                          id="getpid" name="getpid" class="btn btn-primary">


                  <input type="button" name="submit" 
                           id="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Enter Prescription">

             </div>
            </div>
          </form>
```

Here is my `ajax` call

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

var count=0;
$(document).on('click','#add',function() {
    count++; 

    var html= '';
    html += '<tr>';

    html += '<td id="medicinename"> <select  name="med_name[]" id="med_name[]" class="form-control med_name" ><option value=""> Select Medicine</option> <?php echo fill_select_box($conn, "0");  ?></select></td>';
    html += '<td id="mor"> <input type="text" name="morning[]" id="morning[]" class="form-control morning" /> </td>';
    html += '<td id="noo"> <input type="text" name="noon[]" id="noon[]" class="form-control noon" /> </td>';
    html += '<td id="nigh"> <input type="text" name="night[]" id="night[]" class="form-control night" /> </td>';
   // html += '<td class="charge"> </td>';
    html += '<td> <button type="button" name="remove" id="remove" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs remove" >  -  </button> </td>';
    html +=  '</tr>';

    $('#rows').append(html);

});
        });
</script>

 <script>

$(document).ready(function () {
$(document).on('click', '#submit', function () {

    var getapt = $('#getapt').val();  
    var getpid = $('#getpid').val();  

       var ids={ 
            'getapt': getapt,
             'getpid': getpid,
                }

        var modess = $('#rows tr').map(function() {
        let $tr = $(this);

        return [ { 
               "medname": $(this).find('.med_name').val(),
               "morning":$(this).find('.morning').val(),
               "noon":$(this).find('.noon').val(),
               "night": $(this).find('.night').val(),
                 } ]

                 console.log(modess);
                       });

   var ids = JSON.stringify(ids);
   var medical = JSON.stringify(modess);

          $.ajax({
              url: "adminquery/prescription.php", // Url to which the request is send
              method: "POST",             // Type of request to be send, called as method
              data:{
                   index1: medical, 
                   index2: ids
              },
              dataType:'json',             
              cache: false,
              success: function(data){
                alert('Items added');
            },
            error: function(e){
                console.log(e);
            }

          })

});

});
</script>
```

Here is the `php` codes in `prescription.php` page

```
<?php

session_start();
require_once "../auth/dbconnection.php";

// if (isset(json_decode($_POST["data"])) {

  $jsondata = json_decode($_POST["index1"]);
  $jsondata1 = json_decode($_POST["index2"]);

  echo $id= $jsondata1->getpid;
  echo $apt= $jsondata1->getapt;

    if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn,"INSERT INTO prescription (apt_id,user_id,p_id, med_records,date) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)")){

      $cur_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

        $user_id= $_SESSION['user_id'];
        // $p_id= $_POST['getpid'];
        // $apt_id= $_POST['getapt'];

        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "sssss",$apt,$user_id, $id,$jsondata,$cur_date);

       echo "Records inserted successfully.";

} else{

  echo "ERROR: Could not prepare query: $sql. " . mysqli_error($conn);

}

  mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);

?>
```

I don't know where I went wrong. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Remove `dataType: 'JSON'`

Comment: @RiteshKhandekar I removed, after `ajax success` it shows `Records inserted successfully`, when I see the `database` isn't save. There were no record inserted  ?????

Comment: `mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on what I see in your PHP code I understand that you want to store the TEXT of a JSON  `index1` as it goes directly under `med_records` sql element and you want to send PARSE AS AN OBJECT `index2` as you try to decode it and extract two values:

```
  $jsondata1 = json_decode($_POST["index2"]);

  echo $id= $jsondata1->getpid;
  echo $apt= $jsondata1->getapt;
```

Therefore you should decode only on of those and keep the second as string:

```js
$jsondata = $_POST["index1"];
```

as `$jsondata` you want to store just as json string in the database, right? If no then please provide some info about expected data (schema of the table).

Be sure to know that your code is not very safe: first of all it should verify if correct values were even sent (decode parsed data, check for expected keys, encode again), also should be prepared for a case when there is no user id in session anymore.

Comment: Thanks. It works. ;-) . Here when I retrieve this data from `database`, how can I separate these data and shows in separate column in `HTML table`

Comment: I strongly suggest execution of `$.makeArray(modess);`  before you actually store it to avoid jQuery attributes like `length` or `prevObject` being sent too into your database.
Then, having data from the database - for example each record in variable `$row` you can simply use json_decode foreach: `$medRecords = json_decode($row['med_records']);` and later: `foreach($medRecords as $key => $object) { echo `<td>'. $object->morning .'</td>  };` etc.

Comment: Is before I sent to `prescription.php` page.

Comment: What do you mean? The `dataType: 'JSON'` or something else? This setting is not required as actually you encapsulate your jsons as string and send them using standard post format.

Comment: No I mean, `$.makeArray(modess);`. How to achieve this?  How to send these values?? without  `var medical = JSON.stringify(modess);`

Comment: Just change: `var medical = JSON.stringify(modess);` to `var medical = JSON.stringify( $.makeArray(modess) );`